# Хазяйка чи власниця: як правильно?

Tags: значення-слів, росіянізм

У [Словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/vlasnycja) все ж подається визначення обидвох лексем:

ХАЗЯ́ЙКА, и, жін. Жіночий рід до хазяїн.

ВЛА́СНИЦЯ, і, жін. Жіночий рід до власник.

Проте виникає питання: а чи слово "хазяйка" - це, випадково, не калька з російської мови? Чи можна використовувати цю лексему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вжиток

Слово [*власник*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vlasnyk) має єдине значення — особа, яка володіє майновими правами на обʼєкт.

[*Хазяїн*](http://sum.in.ua/s/khazjajin) — більш широке поняття, яке, окрім прав власності на обʼєкт, ще може означати:

- *розпорядник*, у т.ч. тимчасовий;
- *ділова людина* — як властивість характеру;
- *винаймач робочої сили*;

Тому слово *хазяйка* можна використовувати як у ролі синоніма до *власниця*, так і в контексті: *«мама пішла на базар, а донька сьогодні — хазяйка»*, де слово *«власниця»* не застосовується.

#### Етимологія

Словʼянське слово **хазяїн**, [згідно Фасмеру](http://www.endic.ru/fasmer/Hozjain-14984.html), запозичене з татарського.
Слово *ходжа* («вчитель, пан, старець») — споріднене.
Там же вказується, що це слово уперше зустрічається у XIV столітті (1382 рік), за 350 років до створення «російської» мови. Тому ні про яку кальку з російської йтися не може.

#### Чтиво

Є ще слово *господар*, стосовно якого існують [версії](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/host#Etymology_1), що *господар* споріднене з сучасним англійським словом *host* («господар») — через ПІЄ `*gʰóspot-` ("той, хто приймає гостей").

Є ще [*ґазда*](http://sum.in.ua/s/gazda) — яке, схоже, теж походить із того самого ПІЄ `*gʰóspot-`.

Comment: http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15171&page=498
СУМ-20 з вами не погоджується і має таке значення слова "власник": // Хазяїн когось (перев. людей, тварин).

Comment: та й СУМ-11 з вами не погоджується, бо то слово має не єдине, значення, а цілих три, і якщо марксистсько-леніністським можна знехтувати, то оцим - ні: //  Особа, якій властиве щось.

Comment: @P.Vovk, цікаво. Ви можете написати іншу відповідь, яка робить протилежні висновки.

Comment: я думав, ви свою виправите або доповните. наївно, виходить, думав. ладно, як буде час, може, напишу й свою.

Comment: але якщо доповните, то поставлю стрілочку вгору замість стрілочки донизу!